# Dividing a Layout

Tags: android, layout, divide

I got the following activity

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:background="@color/colorGray"
    tools:context=".ProductsActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/navigation"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"></LinearLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
        app:itemIconTint="@drawable/btv_tab_item_foreground"
        app:itemTextColor="@drawable/btv_tab_item_foreground"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:menu="@menu/navigation" />
 </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Inside my LinearLayout, I want to add let's say 6 textviews or buttons or whatever and i want their

- width equal to the parent's width
- height, equal to each other

[image]

Something like the image above (the lines are not adjusted correctly cause they were drawn with MS Paint). But i think you got the point.

Comment: `their height perfectly adjusted to their parent's constraint height`, does this mean you want them equal width to the parent and equal height to each other?

Comment: Yes exactly.  But occupy all available height of their parent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<LinearLayout
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:orientation="vertical">

     <TextView
        android:text="Register"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    // same code as above textView 5 more times 

  </LinearLayout>
```